# I need to accelerate the performance of my WPF Program

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, performance

i'm making a WPF desktop app, i need to display 15,000 elements in a stackpanel with rows and columns, i have 4 elements declared like this:

```
public class PasaImagen
{
    public string imagenbindeada { get; set; }
    public int TiempoDeVida { get; set; }
    //public int Cantidad { get; set; }
}

if (imagenrandom1 == 1)
                    {
                        //string consecutivas = "/foto" + imagenrandom1.ToString() + ".png";
                        items1[i].Add(new PasaImagen { imagenbindeada = "/pasto.png", TiempoDeVida=TiempoDeVidaPasto });
                        matriz1[j, i] = "pasto";
                        listapocicionesdematriz1.Add(i.ToString() + "  , " + j.ToString());
                    }
                    if (imagenrandom1 == 2)
                    {
                        //string consecutivas = "/foto" + imagenrandom1.ToString() + ".png";
                        items1[i].Add(new PasaImagen { imagenbindeada = "/conejo.png", TiempoDeVida=TiempoDeVidaConejo });
                        matriz1[j, i] = "conejo";
                        listapocicionesdematriz1.Add(i.ToString() + "  , " + j.ToString());
                    }
                    if (imagenrandom1 == 3)
                    {
                        //string consecutivas = "/foto" + imagenrandom1.ToString() + ".png";
                        items1[i].Add(new PasaImagen { imagenbindeada = "/lobo.png", TiempoDeVida=TiempoDeVidaLobo });
                        matriz1[j, i] = "lobo";
                        listapocicionesdematriz1.Add(i.ToString() + "  , " + j.ToString());
                    }
                    if (imagenrandom1 == 4)
                    {

                        items1[i].Add(new PasaImagen { imagenbindeada = "/tierra.png" ,TiempoDeVida=TiempoDeVidaTierra });
                        matriz1[j, i] = "tierra";
                        listapocicionesdematriz1.Add(i.ToString() + "  , " + j.ToString());
                    }
```

The real problem is when i have to display them in the stackpanel, when i use 1,000 elements, i have no problem with them, they are continuously moving between one cell to another in a loop, no problem with that, but then i use like 6,000 elements, the performance of the app is very slow, and their movement becomes very slow and poor.

The question is, how can i transform the Uri image or the image in order to make them easier to read for the program and make a better performance when displaying the items when executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should virtualize this.  Try using a container with virutalization.  For details, see the help for [VirtualizingStackPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx).